# Upload a 10GB media file using webdriver IO

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

Objective: Through my application I am trying to upload a ~10GB file using WebDriver IO.

Script:

```
const path = require('path');
const dirPath = path.join(__dirname, 'C:\Users\Dev030126\Downloads\MediaFile\V1.mp4');

const remoteFilePath = browser.uploadFile(dirPath);
$('.upload-data-file-input').setValue(remoteFilePath);
```

Above script is working fine for smaller files but for 10GB or greater it is not successful.

Comment: Are you sure it's a code thing and not a site thing? Maybe the site is rejecting the upload because of size? Also, are you getting an error when it fails? If so, edit your question and add the full error message as text, properly formatted.

Comment: Yeah it is a part of code which is to handle only file upload. Can we implement a batch system for the file upload ?

Comment: Is there an error? What is it?